# Saving entity, with table associated to itself through join table

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm building an App with CakePHP 3.0. I have a FactsTable and an InterferencesTable. Interferences has this fields:

`[id][changed_fact_id][influenced_fact_id][trend][modified_by][modified_at][created_by][created_at]`

associations look like this:

FactsTable:

```php
 `$this->belongsToMany('InfluencedFacts', [
     'through' => 'Interferences',
     'className' => 'Facts',
     'foreignKey' => 'changed_fact_id'
 ]);
 $this->belongsToMany('ChangedFacts', [
     'through' => 'Interferences',
     'className' => 'Facts',
     'foreignKey' => 'influenced_fact_id'
 ]);`
```

InterferencesTable:

```php
`$this->belongsTo('ChangedFacts', [
    'className' => 'Facts',
    'foreignKey' => 'influenced_fact_id',
]);
$this->belongsTo('InfluencedFacts', [
    'className' => 'Facts',
    'foreignKey' => 'changed_fact_id',
]);`
```

I baked my controllers and views. Saving a new Fact works fine but the association isn't saved. I tried to save the association manually but it doesn't work, too.

If i made a mistake in model-association, please tell me ;)

saving code from FactsController.php:

```
`public function add() {
    $fact = $this->Facts->newEntity($this->request->data);
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Facts->save($fact)) {
            $id = $fact->get('id');
            $this->Flash->success('The fact has been saved.');
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error('The fact could not be saved. Please, try again.');
        }
    }
    $aggregates = $this->Facts->Aggregates->find('list');
    $plants = $this->Facts->Plants->find('list');
    $influencedFacts = $this->Facts->InfluencedFacts->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('fact', 'aggregates', 'plants', 'influencedFacts'));
}`
```

Fact Entity:

```
`protected $_accessible = [
    'name' => true,
    'short' => true,
    'description' => true,
    'modified_by' => true,
    'modified_at' => true,
    'created_by' => true,
    'created_at' => true,
    'aggregates' => true,
    'plants' => true,
];`
```

Comment: Did you set `['associated' => true]` when using the `save` method?

Comment: Can you show the saving code? Also, can you show the code for the Fact entity? Usually you need to set the association property name in the $_accesible array

Comment: @Holt: i didn't use `['associated' => true]`. But I just added it and it has no effect.

@José Lorenzo: I added `'influenced_fact_id'=>true,` but i'm not sure if this was the property you mean. besides it didn't hel

Comment: I meant that you needed to add `influenced_facts` and `changed_facts` to the accessible list

Comment: I added `influenced_facts` and `changed_facts` to the Fact Entity but the save fails. Maybe it's something with the associations? Because I'm associating facts with itself through interferences.
When I insert something in my interferences database table everything works as it should.